# What's the difference between Present Perfect and Simple Past?

Tags: difference, tense, past-tense

I have a question about English grammar.
At 1 minute 5 seconds of this video below, Batman says "This city just showed you".
Is it okay to replace it with "This city has shown you", "This city has just shown you." and "This city just has shown you"?

I would be happy if you could answer

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fzx9OpDH8HY&t=64s

Comment: Grammatically, maybe. But it changes the meaning slightly .

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!!
Please tell me more about the slight difference!
I would like to understand the nuances.

Comment: Sigh. I wish when people down vote they would leave a comment as to why. It is not helpful to bomb and leave. Nobody learns and nobody improves.

Comment: Ah...Trying to explain the nuances is always tired...but thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

From a grammar point of view, either is OK.

The form "This city just showed you" implies that it was very recent. In this context, the word "just" indicates that the showing has only finished moments ago. Or possibly it is even still happening, not finished yet.

The form "This city has shown you" implies only that the showing has happened in the past. It does not indicate any particular recentness. It could have been basically any time while the "you" was available to be shown. Maybe it was moments ago. Maybe it was last year. Maybe it was years ago.

Comment: WoooooooooooooooW! Yeah! Thank you very much! Uh...And lastly, there is a question. Is there a difference in meaning between "This city has just shown you." And "This city just has shown you." I would be happy if you could answer ...

Comment: "this city has just shown you" that is the right sequence of words.